# What is the notion of "limiting infinite-dimensional operator" corresponding to limiting spectral distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a $p\times p$ matrix $A_p$, the average eigenvalue can easily be computed by $$ave_i(\lambda_i(A_p)) = \frac 1p\operatorname{tr}(A_p).$$

Suppose that we have a sequence $A_1,\dots,A_p,\dots$ such that $A_p$ converges to a limiting spectral distribution compactly supported in $(0,\infty)$. The definition of the spectral distribution of a matrix $A_p$ is
$$s.d.(A_p) = \frac 1p\sum_{i=1}^p \delta_{\lambda_i(A_p)},$$
where $\delta$ is the dirac-delta the assumption above means that as $p$ goes to infinity this converges to a limiting distribution with compact support.

I believe in this case the notion of "average eigenvalue" is just the expected value of the distribution.

However, for the task I am doing it would be useful to be able to think about this limiting distribution as an operator itself. Does this notion make sense? If so, what properties would this operator have that I can exploit? How would the notion of "average eigenvalue" make sense for this operator?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure the best way to go about things. I've heard it is bad to have duplicate questions on multiple stacks and just posted to MO. Thanks.

Comment: I have put the same Q on both ME and MO, when I failed to get satisfaction on ME, without any criticism.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *(the text below was an answer to the original version of the question)*

You say "intuitively it is obvious that a notion of average eigenvalue should exist". I think, on the other hand, that it is obvious that there is no notion of average eigenvalue.

First of all, your operator may lack eigenvalues at all. So, if $A$ has no eigenvalues and its spectrum is $[1,2]$, what's the "average eigenvalue"?

You could say that you could simply average the spectrum geometrically. Even then, $A$ may have part of the spectrum made up of eigenvalues and part not eigenvalues. You could decide that infinite multiplicitly always trumps finite multiplicity, so you only consider the essential spectrum. Even them, if the spectrum is $$\left\{1,\frac43\right\}\cup\left[\frac53,2\right],$$ what would the "average" be?  There will always be one more pathological case to deal with.

Comment: My understanding is that because $A$ is positive-definite and compact, that therefore its spectrum is discrete and countable and it makes sense to talk about average value.

I am very rusty on this stuff. I may be missing assumptions in my question. I am considering the case where a sequence of $p\times p$ operators converge in spectral distribution to a limiting compact positive-definite infinite-dimensional operator. I want to extend the notion of average eigenvalue to this setting.

Comment: Also, your example includes $0$ in the spectrum. But I assume that the spectrum is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: Your question doesn't say "$A$ is compact". It says that its spectrum is compact, which is true for every bounded operator. In any case, for compacts the spectrum is a sequence converging to zero, so how can you expect to define an "average"?

Comment: Bounded away from zero? I moved my example one unit to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. You have shown me that my question was poorly phrased. I will rephrase more specifically. I think I am missing certain assumptions.

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks for your help. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: No  problem. I'm afraid I cannot help you further, as I have no idea what "converges to a spectral distribution" means.

Comment: I will definite it in the question.